# How to extract a property from array of objects and slice it?

Tags: javascript

so i have an array of objects which returns phoneNumber and businessNumber and name. I am trying to extract the businessNumber and phoneNumber and want to slice them from "-" to only show the last 4 digits?

I was able to use the map to extract the businessNumber but how can i split an return them both in the desired format?

```js
myArray = [{
    phoneNumber: "(111) 222-3344",
    businessNumber: "(112) 333-4567",
    name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    phoneNumber: "(111) 222-3344",
    businessNumber: "(112) 333-4567",
    name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    phoneNumber: "(111) 222-3344",
    businessNumber: "(112) 333-4567",
    name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    phoneNumber: "(111) 222-3344",
    businessNumber: "(112) 333-4567",
    name: "Name1"
  },
]

let arr1 = myArray.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.businessNumber.split('-').pop()
})
console.log(arr1)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get everything after the dash in a string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573145/get-everything-after-the-dash-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: would you be able to provide an example of the output you want? It's not clear from the question. Thanks

Comment: @Finnnn please check the updated code, i made changes to the return line. but what would be the cleanest way of putting this on business and phone number together at the same time?

Comment: @CalvinNunes Thank you that helped but what would be the cleanest way of putting this on business and phone number together at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could return both numbers in an array of new objects

```
let arr1 = myArray.map(function(obj) {
  return {
    businessNumber: obj.businessNumber.split('-').pop(),
    phoneNumber: obj.phoneNumber.split('-').pop() 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you change your map function slightly.

```js
myArray = [{
    phoneNumber: "(111) 222-3344",
    businessNumber: "(112) 333-4567",
    name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    phoneNumber: "(111) 222-3344",
    businessNumber: "(112) 333-4567",
    name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    phoneNumber: "(111) 222-3344",
    businessNumber: "(112) 333-4567",
    name: "Name1"
  },
  {
    phoneNumber: "(111) 222-3344",
    businessNumber: "(112) 333-4567",
    name: "Name1"
  },
]

let updatedArr = myArray.map((obj) => {
  obj.phoneNumber = obj.phoneNumber.split('-').pop()
  obj.businessNumber = obj.businessNumber.split('-').pop()
  return(obj);
})
console.log(updatedArr)
```