# How to modify objects in an array?

Tags: javascript

i have an array of objects that gives out information in the below shown format.

```js
personArray = [{
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
]
```

How can i Get the output to display the object as 
and so on. So basically only the phone number is edited in a sense to hide anything before the `-`

```
{
name:'Person1',
number:"2282",
membership:"standard"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573145/get-everything-after-the-dash-in-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @CalvinNunes i tried the first one but that only seems to return the number i guess but i still want to return the whole array back with the modified number.

Comment: i came to give you a upvote inspite of the downvoters. Il do it for the duplicate markers too.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to loop the array and do your manipulation

```js
const edited = personArray.map(e => {
  e.number = e.number.substring(e.number.indexOf('-') + 1);
  return e;
});

console.log(edited);
```

```html
<script>
const personArray = [{
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
]
</script>
```

Note that you could also use `forEach` and manipulate `personArray` directly without mapping it to a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the phone number as you wish using a simple `.replace` call with regex.

```js
let phone = "(770) 556-2282";
let phone2 = phone.replace(/.*-/, '');
console.log(phone2);
```

To apply this to all the objects in the array, simply iterate them with `.forEach` (or `.map` if you don't wish to modify the original objects and array).

```js
let personArray = [{
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
];

personArray.forEach(p => p.number = p.number.replace(/.*-/, ''));

console.log(personArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
const personArray = [{
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person1',
    number: "(770) 556-2282",
    membership: 'standard'
  },
];

const updatedArray = personArray.map(user => {
  const indexToRemove = user.number.indexOf('-');
  const number = user.number.slice(indexToRemove + 1);
  return {...user, number};
});

console.log(updatedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++){
    let indexChar = personArray[i].number.indexOf('-');
    personArray[i].number = personArray[i].number.substring(indexChar + 1);
}
```

Search where is the '-' char and than take the right side of the number.