# Check something exists after `group/`

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a url like so: `group/wtbxqcum`
This is a dynamic part: `wtbxqcum`

How to check if something exists after  `group/`?

I was able to do this if URL is like so: `group?type=all`

**e.g.**

```
 if (authReq.url.indexOf('type=all') >= 0) {
   //code
    }
```

**P.S.**

My URL is like so: `authReq.url = 'Prod/v1/group/wtbxqcum';`

Comment: `authReq.url.indexOf('group/') === 0 && authReq.url.length > 'group/'.length` ...?

Comment: `if (/^group\/.+$/.test(authReq.url)) {`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573145/get-everything-after-the-dash-in-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, it is not working.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry, it is not working.

Comment: @Sampath really? Run `/^group\/.+$/.test("group/blah")` or `/^group\/.+$/.test("group/")` in console. Can you see the output? It's `true` for the first and `false` for the second.

Comment: What are you talking about? https://jsfiddle.net/3hg05jqm/

Comment: _"Sorry, it is not working"_ - seriously? You got 63k rep here ... Please do better than _that_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could achieve this the following ways:

1. find index of "group/", then add 6 (no. of chars in 'group/') & compare it with the length.
2. split the string at "group/" and check if the second element in the returned array isn't empty.

```js
const str = "blah/group/dynamicStr"
const n = 6 // no of chars in "group/"
if (str.indexOf("group/") + n < str.length){
  console.log("something exists")
  // str.substr(str.indexOf("group/")+n, str.length) will return the value that exists
} else {
  console.log("nothing exists")
}

// or

const a = str.split("group/")
if (a.length == 2 && a[1] != ''){
  console.log(a[1], " exists")
}else {
  console.log("nothing exists")
}
```